# Eagle via option 1-16 not shown

Tags: eaglecad, via, cad

For this one eagle drawing, I am not seeing the via option for 1-16 layer. I can only put a via connecting layer 1-2 (see attached). If I try to change layer while routing from top to bottom, I get the layer "*can't set via to layer 1* ".

I have not experienced this before. It has to something simple I am missing. Could you please let me what it is, if you do.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: What are the layer settings in your DRC?

Comment: For a two layer board you should have something like `(1*16)` for the stackup. I'm going to guess that yours is `(1*2)`.

Comment: Dang, yes that was the issue. The drc was set to (1*2). Thanks for pointing out the error. Thanks Tom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The available vias are based on the DRC Layers setup. On the DRC window, go to the `Layers` tab, and look for the box labelled `Setup`. This is where you specify how many layers are in your design, but also whether there are any blind or buried vias too.

[image: Screenshot of DRC Layers Panel]

For a two layer board, Eagle normally uses layer 1 (Top) and layer 16 (Bottom). As such your DRC setup needs to be `(1*16)`. That string means that you have a board using layers 1 and 16 {`1 16`}, there is a core substrate layer between {`*`}, and that there are vias that go between these layers {`(   )`}.

For more complicated boards like 4-layer, you might have a string like `(1+2*15+16)` which indicates layers 1, 2, 15, and 16 are used, with a core layer separating 2 and 15, then prepreg layers between 1 and 2 and between 15 and 16. Finally the only available via goes from layer 1 to 16, connecting to all in between.

---

In your case you will instead have the string `(1*2)` which means that your bottom layer would be on layer `2` rather than `16` (bottom). Simply changing the 2 to be 16 will fix the issue.